# Is there any way to see the content of the theme registry?

Tags: theming

I was wondering if there is a way to see (print out) the content of the theme registry.

I've looked in the database; it seems to be stored in the cache table, if I understand things right, but the theme registry itself is stored as a blog.

When I looked at the blog, I couldn't seem to make any sense of what was there. It all seemed to look like hex values.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see the content of the theme registry, you can use [_theme_load_registry()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/_theme_load_registry/7). The first argument could be the global `$theme` for the currently used theme, or one of the objects returned by [list_themes()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/list_themes/7).
As the function name is prefixed by an underscore, I would suggest to use it only for debugging purposes. (Theoretically, future Drupal versions could drop those *private* functions, and that would not probably be taken as API change.)

If you have installed [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel), you can use the following code:

```
global $theme;

$registry = _theme_load_registry($theme);
dsm($registry);
```

You can also simply visit the devel/theme/registry page which shows you the theme registry content.

Answer (score 1):

See [theme_get_registry()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_get_registry/7)

This simple function returns an array of theme registry

Answer (score 0):

[hook_theme_registry_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/6) can help in this regard.

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry){
```

`$theme_registy` would result entire theme registry information.

The hook is invoked as the theme cache is re-built